# Regular expression in htaccess for 301 redirects

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I don't know why it doesn't work but what I want:

Old links: http://krater.hu/krater.php*******
new links: http://regi.krater.hu/krater.php*******

My code is (But i was trying with a lot of things and still not working):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/krater\.php(.+)$ http://regi.krater.hu/krater.php$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Can someone help me out please? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule on your old host:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(krater\.php(.*))$ http://regi.krater.hu/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

- Remove leading slash in URL pattern in htaccess
- Don't se `.+` after `.php`

Comment: WHOOAAA Thank you very much!!!!! It works finally!! ^^ (wordpress addon redirection stripped out the square brackets from url's) Thank you!!!!